# Javascript not changing background img in a span

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've recently tried to use some js code that i've used for ages to change a span's background colour on certain days, i'm now trying to use the js to change the background image instead but i'm having issues.
The js is finding the element but rather than change to the new image, the page is just rendering the span with no image at all.
Any hints would be handy as i'm not that great with js. I do have spans identified to display as block, and the current image in the span does work when the javascript is removed.

Javascript code: (i've cut some out so only Thursday has a command)

```
var d = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
var thursday = document.getElementById("th");

if (n == "Thursday") {
thursday.style.color="#fff";
thursday.style.backgroundImage = "url(../images/boardMiddleOn.png)";
}
```

CSS:

```
#th {
background-image:url(../images/boardMiddle.png);
height: 45px;
line-height: 45px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span id="th">Thursday: 9am - 11pm<br/></span>
```

Comment: Is the css file in another directory? if so, then the path set in the html page should be different.

Comment: Your span should probably be set to display block or inline block and given a width.

Comment: Hi, the css and javascript files are in their own folders in the main directory.
So at root level I have the page html files, then in folders in that directory I have a CSS folder and a Javascript folder. I figured the root to the source might be off, but i'm not sure what I should change.
The javascript link is at the bottom before the closing body tag.

Comment: When the image is called from the html page, the path to the image must be relative to the page. change the url to `./images/boardMiddle.png`